Optimizing Apollo API Calls with Generic Function and Enum (Swift)
I'm working on a Swift project using Apollo as the client and ApolloCodegen to generate GraphQL queries and mutations. I have numerous APIs, and I'd like to streamline the process of making calls.
Goal:
My objective is to create a generic performQuery() function that simplifies API calls based on an APIList enum. Each enum case represents an API, and the corresponding query type can be any class generated by ApolloCodegen.
Desired Functionality:
The performQuery() function should:
Take an APIList case and a completion handler (resultHandler) as arguments.
Return an object of the specific query type based on the APIList case using a generic Query parameter.
Utilize Apollo's fetch method to execute the query and handle the result in the completion handler.
Challenge:
The challenge is that apollo.fetch expects a concrete GraphQLQuery object, and we don't have that information upfront due to ApolloCodegen's dynamic generation. We cannot create a generic wrapper around GraphQLQuery because the specific data structures are unknown.
Question:
How can I create a single generic function in Swift that provides the appropriate queries for different APIs based on the APIList case passed as an argument, ensuring type safety and seamless Apollo integration?
Example Code for better understanding of problem:
I expect query.query() to return required query object on the basis of passed parameters and performQuery() function to somehow infer generic parameter 'Query'.
public func performQuery<Query: GraphQLQuery>( _ query: APIList, resultHandler: ((Result<GraphQLResult<Query.Data>, SensonicError>) -> Void)?) {
   
      apollo.fetch(query: query.query()) { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let data):
          // Do something
        case .failure(let error):
          break
        }
         
      }
    }
  }  

APIList enum -

public enum APIList2 {

    case getAmenity(amenityId: String)
    case getAmenityCategory(amenityCategoryId: String)
    var rawValue: String {
        switch self {
        case .getAmenity:
            "getAmenity"
            
        case .getAmenityCategory:
            "getAmenityCategory"
        }
        
    }

public func query() -> /* what should I write here */ {
        switch self {
        case .getAmenity(let amenityId):
            return AmenityNs.GetAmenityQuery(amenityId: amenityId, platform: Platform.pf1.rawvalue)
        
        case .getAmenityCategory(let categoryId):
            return AmenityNs.GetAmenityCategoryByIDQuery(amenityCategoryId: categoryId, platform: Platform.pf2.rawValue, recipient: .none)
            
        }
    }
}

Tried to create a wrapper around GraphQLQuery class but I cannot make every auto Generated class to conform to that wrapper and also cannot provide required protocol stubs individually for every class.
